# Can't solve "Bad Address" error in truncated fwrite

Tags: c, fwrite

I realize that getting the "bad address" error from fwrite is *usually* because you either have a corrupted pointer or an insufficiently large buffer.  However, this does not appear to be my issue, and I cannot think of any other scenario that could cause this.

I have verified:

- The pointer to the allocated buffer is valid
- The allocated size is larger than the specified fwrite size
- The fwrite succeeds in writing about 2/3rds of the data.
- That much data actually does end up on the disk drive.

In my actual run, w = 5, rows = 750,152, bufSizeBytes = 6,001,216, and bytesLen = 3,750,760, so the buffer is larger than it needs to be.  However, the fwrite reports bytes actually written as 2,252,800 (confirmed on disk), and gives an error 14.

Note that when I filled up the buffer, I did not get any particular access error - I have no idea what could be limiting this to just 2.2MB.  (My hard drive is also not out of space.) :)

Here's my actual code, with ancillary parts removed:

```
    // This gives you an instant pointer cast

    typedef union
        {
        U8* b;
        void*   v;
    [ ... ]
        } olGenericPointer_t;

    // NOW in the function of interest:

    olGenericPointer_t pColumnBuf;
    S64 bufSizeBytes = sizeof(S64) * rows;
    pColumnBuf.v = malloc(bufSizeBytes); // handle max word size


    // Later in the code, after filling up the buffer with some data, we try to save it to disk...


    S64 bytesLen = w * rows;
    S64 bytes_written = 0;
    bytes_written = fwrite(pColumnBuf.v, 1, bytesLen, fp);

    if (bytes_written != rows * w)
        {
        printf("Error - only wrote %s of %s bytes to file %s: ",
                     olPrintInt(bytes_written), olPrintInt(rows*w),
                    pszOutput);

        printf("Error code is %d / %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
        ff();
        }

    // close column file (should flush)
    olClose(fp);
```

Comment: Thanks so much to the user who magically reformatted my question - how did you force the system to accept it?

Comment: You can see the diff by clicking on the "edited by" link (http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29752311/revisions), then choose the "Markdown" view. You indented some non-code lines by four spaces apparently.

Comment: As for your error: you're printing errno without checking if the function actually failed. That's meaningless.

Comment: SOLVED it!  I'm a complete idiot.  I was incrementing the original pointer to the buffer and then using it as the original buffer again.  Sorry so much to waste your time, stack overflow folks.

Comment: As shameful as this post is, I think may still be of use to others who made similar mistakes in formatting and fwrite usage.

Comment: Subcomments:  Mat, I indented non code lines because it was the only way to get this posted.  It thought I didn't have enough code in the post.   Printing the error code before catching the error was just a hack because the assert already caught the error - I will now make this into more respectable code.  Thanks so much everyone - I appreciate the help.

Comment: The clever tip off here was that the amount actually written happened to be the difference in size between the buffer and the fwrite size.  That was the significance of 2,252,800. :)

Comment: Thanks for the clue friends. Even i had the same issue while building, `mvn clean package`. 
it got resolved after cleaning the untracked/unwanted files with `git clean -d -f -x`